# How many clears are necessary to get to the final ending of Hades?

Tags: hades

In Hades, you could consider 1 ending being the 'clear once', or the credits ending being the final ending, that happens at about 10 clears.

But on Steam, there's a very rare achievement, called 'see the epilogue'. So I guess there's a 'final' ending, but how much clears do you need to trigger it? (Or if the completion is something else, what is the requirements that are needed and, if not too variable, at how much clears do people usually get there?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, reading the Gamepedia wiki's [Epilogue Guide](https://www.hades.gamepedia.com/Epilogue_Guide), the epilogue requirements are mostly to max out affinity with all the gods, and then discuss with everybody.

The story will then move forward for the epilogue.

Comment: Im at about 30 escape and 120 attempts and I'm at the step of giving invitations. Might have been slow getting there tho

Comment: So yeah, here's pretty much was is needed, in my experience. Full Hearts with all the 'boon gods' except Aphrodite and Demeter. Had full hearts with everybody except Than and the 2 godesses.